# Want to align a dropdown to the right end using css grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-grid

I am learning to use css grid. I want to align a responsive drop down to the right using css grid. I am aware that there would be many ways to get this simple requirement done, but I want to get it done using css grid. I have taken the dropdown code from bootstrap for quick work. Code is below. the dropdown is not aligned to the right extreme. Please help.

```css
/*
#mydiv ul{
    text-align:right;
}*/
/*#mydiv ul { list-style:none;}*/

#mydiv {
    grid-column-start: 250;
    grid-column-end:300;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class = "container" id="mydiv">
  <ul>
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu-right" href="#" id="mydiv" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `mydiv` id on your dropdown link, you should remove it (removed in my example). Otherwise it may mess you up later.

Also, to have more control over where the dropdown appears, you can use columns in the grid and tell the rendering engine which column to place yur element in.

`justify-self:end` will tell the element to stick to the right edge of the column.

However, this makes the dropdown to be cropped onn the right edge, so you may need to play around with it.

[More details on css columns](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

```css
#mydiv {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: end;
  grid-template-columns: 70% 30%
}

#mydiv ul {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  justify-self: end;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class = "container" id="mydiv">
  <ul>
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu-right" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It is working, but I am trying to understand how it works. You have given grid-template-columns: 70% 30% . But we don't have 2 columns, right?. Even in index.html, there is only 1 inner div. I am going thru your link, but could you also please elaborate. Thanks!.

Comment: That's exactly the role of the CSS grid: to forgo the use of many divs and hacking a grid system together. It divides an element virtually and places the elements on those divisions. It's like placing elements to absolute positions, but on steroids.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use `grid` then you need to add that property.
Very basic example what may help you is this:

```
#mydiv {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: end;
//your old properties
  grid-column-start: 250;
  grid-column-end:300;
}
```

Anyway taking into account that for grid it is better to specify rows/cols.

Comment: The dropdown symbol has disappeared.